# Android - Accessing app private folder getFilesDir() path from file manager app

Tags: android, debugging, storage

I need to access the private folder of my app for debugging purposes.
I use `myActivity.getFilesDir()` 
to handle the private folder but I cannot see it in the filesystem when using the file manager.

Before, I used `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and I could see the    `com.myDomain.app` folder in the `Android/data` directory and I was able to open it and check the private files for debug.

Now, how can I access the `getFilesDir()` 
folder from the file manager?

Comment: your question is not clear..do you want path of your package?

Comment: @Prachi Singh I edited the question. I meant accessing the folder from the file manager app

Comment: not able to understand..but if you want to access yor app files then use `getExternalFilesDir("")`, it will give you path of your apps files

Comment: @Prachi Singh My app works as to the files in the getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() folder. I just want to open some json files that the app put there in a text editor. But I do not see the directory in the file manager, while before I could see it (when using Environment.getExternalStorageDIrectory()). I need to use getFilesDir() so I have not to put permission requests in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The directory I used to see being created in `/Android/data` path is found by means of the `getExternalFilesDir(null)` method call.

I saw an example with the null parameter, and it works for me.

I replaced all `getFilesDir()` instances in my code files with `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, for debugging purposes.

That folder is correctly created and accessible: `/Android/data/com.mydomain.app`

Every other app is using that folder, even if it is accessible to the user.

I do not know whether I will end up using that folder or the hidden (as far it seems) one.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the Android security system. The private files of an application can only be accessed by the application itself. You only have a few options:

1. Add some code to your application that lets you view, dump or copy the private files. I typically make such code dependant on DEBUG builds so that I don't accidentally release it into production.
2. Move the storage to a public location. I don't typically like this because you have to change code between testing and production, which risks mistakes.
3. Save files on to an SD card and then access it outside of the device so you are not subject to Android restrictions.
4. Root the phone so you can bypass the normal restrictions.

If you make some simple code to copy all private files to a public location, then you can write your production code, but with debug builds, you can get it to snapshot the files for debugging.

Hope that helps.